# PHP- How to validate checkbox and textbox in php?

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap

[Screenshot](https://ibb.co/nn418F) I'm trying to validate a checkbox and multiple textboxes. The textboxes should be disabled at first, and should be enabled only when the checkbox is ticked. Also an alert should pop up if a textbox on the same row of the ticked checkbox is left empty.

```
             <table class="table table-bordered"> 
    <tr align="center" style="background-color:black; color:white;">
               <tr> <td colspan="8" style="background-color:silver;"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="addSPtoCart" name="addSPtoCart" value="Add To Cart" class="button-L" /></td></tr>
                <tr align="center" style="background-color:black; color:white;">    
               <td class="border"><span class="table-head"><label>Favorite</label></span></td>  
              <td><span class="table-head"><label>Material Code</label></span></td>
              <td><span class="table-head"><label>Material Desc</label></span></td>
              <td><span class="table-head"><label>Chart</label></span></td>
              <td><span class="table-head"><label>Shade</label></span></td>
              <td><span class="table-head"><label><?php echo $month1 ?></label></span></td>
              <td><span class="table-head"><label><?php echo $month2 ?></label></span></td>
              <td><span class="table-head"><label><?php echo $month3 ?></label></span></td>
              <!--<td class="no-border" align="center"><span class="table-head">Action</span></td>-->
             </tr>

    <tr class="abc" align="center">
                  <style>.abc:nth-child(even){background-color: silver;}</style>  
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="fav[]" id="fav[]" value="<?php echo $d['materialID']; ?>" /></td>
              <td><label><?php echo $d['materialCode']; ?></label></td>
              <td><label><?php echo $d['materialDesc']; ?></label></td>
              <td><label><?php echo $d['chart']; ?></label></td>
              <td><label><?php echo $d['shade']; ?></label></td>
              <td><input type="text"   class="form-control" style="width:80px; " size ="5" name="qty_1<?php echo $d['materialID'] ?>" id="qty_1<?php echo $d['materialID'] ?>" value =<?php echo $var1 ?> ></td>
              <td><input type="text"   class="form-control" style="width:80px;" size ="5" name="qty_2<?php echo $d['materialID'] ?>" id="qty_2<?php echo $d['materialID'] ?>" value =<?php echo $var2 ?> ></td>
              <td><input type="text"  class="form-control" style="width:80px;" size ="5" name="qty_3<?php echo $d['materialID'] ?>" id="qty_3<?php echo $d['materialID'] ?>" value =<?php echo $var3 ?> ></td>

            <!--  <td class="no-border" align="center"><a href="<?php //echo SITEURL; ?>/salesplan/salesplan-details/?id=<?php //echo $d['mmID']; ?>&mCatID=<?php// echo $_REQUEST["mCatID"];?>  ">View</a></td> -->

            </tr>

               <tr><td colspan="8"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="addSPtoCart" name="addSPtoCart" value="Add To Cart" class="button-L" /></td></tr>

</table>

 <script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["frmFav"]["qty_1"].value;
        var y = document.forms["frmFav"]["qty_2"].value;
            var z = document.forms["frmFav"]["qty_3"].value;
            //var a = document.forms["frmFav"]["fav"].value;



    if ((x == "") || (!this.frmFav.fav.checked)) {
        alert("This field cannot be left empty !");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Provide a jsfiddle link of what you have tried yet ?

Comment: @AbhaySinghania..refer this [fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nidhi_akbari_1994/4gwrwgbo/)

Comment: Just to be clear: The validation code that you've included in the question is JavaScript. You will need to validate it in PHP **as well** as in JavaScript, because users can bypass JavaScript in the browser, so you cannot rely on the JS validation being done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make onclick action for the button to call validateForm() function

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="addSPtoCart" name="addSPtoCart" value="Add To Cart" class="button-L" onclick="return validateForm()"/>
```

For enable and disable the textbox, put a disabled attribute first

```
<td><input type="text"   class="form-control" style="width:80px; " size ="5" name="qty_1<?php echo $d['materialID'] ?>" id="qty_1<?php echo $d['materialID'] ?>" value =<?php echo $var1 ?> disabled></td>
```

And function to trigger enable and disable the box

```
 function checkboxchange(x){
 var formcontrol = x.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("form-control");
 for (var i = 0; i < formcontrol.length; i++){
     if(formcontrol[i].disabled)
        formcontrol[i].disabled = false;
    else
        formcontrol[i].disabled = true;
 }
}
```

And add function call in the checkbox

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="fav[]" id="fav[]" value="<?php echo $d['materialID']; ?>" onchange="checkboxchange(this)"/></td>
```

Hope that help

Update to the validateForm() function

```
function validateForm() {
var validate = document.querySelectorAll(".form-control:not(:disabled)");
for (var i = 0; i < validate.length; i++){
    if (validate[i].value=="") {
        alert("This field cannot be left empty !");
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks man. The checkbox function is working, but the required field validation is not working.

Comment: Also on checkbox selection all the textboxes are being enabled. I just want the texboxes on the same row as checkbox to be enabled and disabled.

Comment: ohh... i edited for the checkbox one. add a this for the checkbox html, and also function change. Now should be ok for only the checked row

Comment: for the validation function, it should be done in your validateForm() function.... you better check what you want to check before submit

Comment: Thanks a lot bro. You're a life saver :D